# How to format .json data on .txt file using PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am converting an array to JSON format using `json_encode`. Once this is done I want to save this data on a text file at least in a readable way. Here's what I have so far:

```
$keywords = parseTweet ( $tweet, $tweet_id );
// print_r ( $keywords );

$json = json_encode ( $keywords, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
print_r ( $json );

$fp = fopen('index.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $json);
fclose($fp);
```

Unfortunately the respective on the respective .json file (opening it as .txt) I have:

```
{"0":{"type":"RT","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"1":
{"type":"iGamingSummit","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"2":
{"type":"CEO","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"5":
{"type":"guest","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"6":
{"type":"keynote","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"7":
{"type":"speaker","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"8":
{"type":"SiGMA2014","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"9":
{"type":"http","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"10":
{"type":"t","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"11":
{"type":"co","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"12":
{"type":"n5hPpTV1bH","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"}}
```

As you can see it is quite unreadable, moreover I would like to create an index on this .json file where every type appears with its respective frequency and tweet ID, and I also would like to sort this index by type, and I don't think this format will be easy to manage to achieve this.

I am looking to get something like this perhaps:

```
{"0":{
        "type":"RT",
        "frequency":1,
        "tweet_id":"516575570168385537"
  } ... etc
```

Is there a way to format JSON to make it more readable or should I reconsider from using it and maybe try with CSV or something better which won't clog my index file with curly brackets and all the "0", "1"... values?

**-------- UPDATE ---------**

I tried using the suggestion in the first answer but now here's what the text file looks like:

```
{    "0": {        "type": "app",        "frequency": 1,        "tweet_id": "561522539340771328"    },    "1": {        "type": "cat",        "frequency": 1,        "tweet_id": "561522673805975553"    },    "2": {        "type": "dog",        "frequency": 1,        "tweet_id": "561522539340771328"    },    "3": {       "type": "Deed",        "frequency": 1,        "tweet_id": "561522453118464000"    },    "4": {        "type": "deep",        "frequency": 1,        "tweet_id": "542089120651440129"    },    "5": {        "type": "dig",        "frequency": 1,        "tweet_id": "535817228927901696"    }
```

Its as if the indentation **is** happening however the line is not being skipped  to output in the proper way:

```
{
    "0": {
        "type": "app",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "561522539340771328"
    },
    "1": {
        "type": "cat",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "561522673805975553"
    },
    "2": {
        "type": "dog",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "561522539340771328"
    },
    "3": {
        "type": "Deed",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "561522453118464000"
    },
    "4": {
        "type": "deep",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "542089120651440129"
    },
    "5": {
        "type": "dig",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "535817228927901696"
    }
```

This is the code I have that is performing the outcome:

```
$json_index = array_values($json_index);    
$json = json_encode ( $json_index, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
print_r($json);

$index = fopen ( $index_path, 'w' );
fwrite ( $index, $json);
fclose ( $index );
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Why not manipulate the data as *JSON*, not plain text?

Comment: I understand what you mean, would I still be able to sort the index file by type though? I keep thinking that there must be a better, more readable way to do it!

Comment: Why the downvotes? What did I do wrong?

Comment: That seems pretty readable to me.  Can you post a sample of what type of output you would prefer?

Comment: Re-edited with the preferred output

Comment: For goodness sakes, open these files in a proper reader like Sublime Text or Atom or something, not just Notepad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said you don't want to "clog my index file with curly brackets and all the '0', '1'... values." Well, that's how JSON is structured by definition. I'm not sure what you're expecting to be different.

That said, you can make it somewhat easier to read. If you're looking for prettier layout, with line breaks and indentation, use the [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$keywords = parseTweet ( $tweet, $tweet_id );
// print_r ( $keywords );

$json = json_encode ( $keywords, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
print_r ( $json );

$fp = fopen('index.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $json);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is talking about, but I admit, it's unclear.

Comment: @AlexisKing Yeah, it's a weird question. Sounds like OP wants JSON that... isn't JSON. I've clarified my answer somewhat.

Comment: I have updated the question with the outcome using this method however it is still not exactly working, is the code that I have added correct?

Comment: You need to check the line-endings settings in your editor. I'm betting you're on Windows, using an editor that expects line endings of `\r\n` and doesn't recognize just `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want an *array* JSON ? Like that:

```
[
  {
    "type":"RT",
    "frequency":1,
    "tweet_id":"516575570168385537"
  },
  {
    "type":"iGamingSummit",
    "frequency":1,
    "tweet_id":"516575570168385537"
  },
  {
    "type":"CEO",
    "frequency":1,
    "tweet_id":"516575570168385537"
  }
]
```

If so, you just have to use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` constant and ensure that your tweet array has numeric keys using `array_values`.

```
$keywords = array_values($keywords);
$json = json_encode ( $keywords, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

If I grab the object JSON from your sample to test it out :

```
<?php

$keywords = json_decode('{"0":{"type":"RT","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"1":{"type":"iGamingSummit","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"2":{"type":"CEO","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"5":{"type":"guest","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"6":{"type":"keynote","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"7":{"type":"speaker","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"8":{"type":"SiGMA2014","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"9":{"type":"http","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"10":{"type":"t","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"11":{"type":"co","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"},"12":{"type":"n5hPpTV1bH","frequency":1,"tweet_id":"516575570168385537"}}');

/*
 * Force object to array
 */
$arrayValues = array();
foreach($keywords as $value) {
    $arrayValues[] = $value;
}

// You must have at least PHP 5.4
$json = json_encode($arrayValues, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$index = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/test.txt', 'w' );
fwrite ($index, $json);
fclose ($index);
```

My test.txt file contains :

```
[
    {
        "type": "RT",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "iGamingSummit",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "CEO",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "guest",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "keynote",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "speaker",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "SiGMA2014",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "http",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "t",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "co",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "n5hPpTV1bH",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing it as a CSV would make it very 'human readable' which seems to be your intent.

Directly from PHP.net fputscsv
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

The above example will write the following to file.csv:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the examples above I decoded you're example and then recoded it and wrote it to file, seems legit, with an output of:

```
[
    {
        "type": "RT",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "iGamingSummit",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "CEO",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "guest",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "keynote",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "speaker",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "SiGMA2014",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "http",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "t",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "co",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    },
    {
        "type": "n5hPpTV1bH",
        "frequency": 1,
        "tweet_id": "516575570168385537"
    }
]
```

Using you're example code this looks like:

```
$keywords = parseTweet ( $tweet, $tweet_id );

file_put_contents("index.json",
    json_encode(
        array_values($keywords),
        JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
    )
);
```

Remember that if you read this output back into PHP that PHP will ignore the formatting, this is purely for opening the file in a text editor or vim or something.